# How do I reset/clear some or all Firebase Event Types for my App instance

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

As the title states I unfortunately exhausted all 500 unique event types allowed per app instance for Firebase Analytics events. This is due to a bug in my app.

This causes the error 8

> App Instance logs more than 500 unique event types

Extra events are then dropped as per documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors)

Now, how do I clear my app instance to start from scratch again so that I can properly implement a fixed reasonable amount of Firebase Analytics events in my next release of the Android app?

My events are exported to BigQuery as well, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that there's [no way to reset or retire old event types](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/vtPtl1Zx1Ag?pli=1).  If you are unable to use the 500 event types you already defined, you will need to start a new Firebase project.